SQLite - Aggregated Fuctions Doesn't Seem To Be Working
I'm trying out a simple SUM calculations on Sqlite but it does not seem to work. And thus, I have to remove the SUM function and manually calculate each returned data with a calculator on my own.
SELECT
    yp.Value AS total_yogurtprod,
    yp.Year
FROM yogurt_production yp JOIN cheese_production cp 
ON yp.State_ANSI = cp.State_ANSI 
WHERE yp.Year = 2022



But if I add in the SUM (which was what I wanted) the results are wrong.
SELECT
    SUM(yp.Value) AS total_yogurtprod,
    yp.Year
FROM yogurt_production yp JOIN cheese_production cp 
ON yp.State_ANSI = cp.State_ANSI 
WHERE yp.Year = 2022


May I know if anyone knows why?
I thought I did the syntax for the SUM wrongly, and tried searching for the right one but can't seems to see a difference in the way I wrote it. I was hoping that the SUM fuction can help add everything for the yogurt production together.

How many rows do you have? What sum did you expect?

I'm pretty sure the answer is that total_yogurtprod is a 64-byte integer that rolled over.

Hmm may help to better understand your high level goal here... is the output supposed to be the total production of yogurt and cheese in a given year grouped by state? or rather can you spell out the original thin you're after in "plain english"

@MooingDuck I'm not sure what sum to expect but I think its lesser than 64 digits. Is there a way to take a look at the full number?

@shaunhusain I would like to find the total yougurt production for states in the year 2022, which also have cheese production data from 2022. But I'm not sure why does the SUM function not seem to be working. I know I made a mistake, just not sure where it is.

How many rows do you have? What value did you expect for the sum?

So when you do the join I think you are actually wanting something more like a union or else you end up "creating" extra rows for each thing in the left table it will repeat for each match in the right table, hence trying to understand the overall goal.  If you need to know the total of both productions grouped by year and grouped by state for the sum to "work" you'll need those added to the group by part of the statement.

Sounds like ultimately want a list of each state and the total productions summed per state and year, let me know if I'm understanding it wrong though
